# NullReferenceException from EWS Nuget

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using `Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Api 2.2.1.2` Nuget package to send email from EWS 2016.
Sometimes I am getting exception given below. Email is sent out and saved to Sent Items folder as well, so looks like this is not a server issue and seems like somehow Nuget package is throwing this misleading error.

Has anyone encountered this?

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream(Stream responseStream, String contentEncoding)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetResponseStream(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.CreateItem(Item item, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName destinationFolderName)
   at Elliott.CollateralMgmt.Common.Email.Emailer.SendEws(Email email, Boolean isHtml, Dictionary`2 attachments) in /app/Elliott.CollateralMgmt.Common/Email/Emailer.cs:line 162
```

Comment: very same issue here- have you found a solution?

Comment: I have not found a permanent solution. Still happens occasionally.

Comment: i cloned this repo like Henrik said, referenced it from my project and then was able to debug the issue. The bug in the EWS library is that the ContentEnconding parameter to WrapStream is null, but they attempt to .ToLowerInvariant it. You can just fix this in the source code, recompile & reference it and the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging such issues I recommend that you download the sources from:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api

You will then be able to add breakpoint and step into the Library code

I your specific problem, you should take a look at

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream
```

Comment: i cloned this repo, referenced it from my project and then was able to debug the issue. The bug in the EWS library is that the ContentEnconding parameter to WrapStream is null, but they attempt to .ToLowerInvariant it. You can just fix this in the source code, recompile & reference it and the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this with the nuget EWS 2.2.0 package.  I found that I didn't hit this issue when referencing the git source https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api instead of the nuget package for EWS 2.2.0 - depending on how you're using EWS, this might work for you.